# Custom Page Break in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a matrix report with several columns. I am trying to limit number of rows displayed on each page by inserting a page break. Since it has row groups all the data is growing vertically down on one page. Is there a way where I can control the number of rows on a page?

I have googled it a lot and found the solution where the rows were detail but in my case they all are row groups

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How is your dataset being generated? If it's T-SQL, do you have any ability to chnage this to suit your reporting requirements?

Comment: The data set is generated using T -sql... I am not sure how to do at data set level to suit my report requirements.